# Private NuGet v.3 feed

Tags: nuget, nuget-server, .net-core

I have a private NuGet 2.8.5 feed in my internal network, which I use as part of my environment.

I just found that it does not work with some new packages.
Particularly, [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.dnx/2.1.0-beta3-build99) reference the same assembly for two different evironments - **DNX 4.5.1** and **DNXCore 5.0**

That causes following error:

> 'xunit.runner.dnx' already has a dependency defined for
>   'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions'.

It looks like NuGet v.2 problem.

[NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com) UI tool has exactly the same problem...

So, how can I create a local NuGet v.3 feed, which could serve such packages?

This [NuGet.Server package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nuget.server) looks abandoned, and I'm not able to find its source code anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2.8.6 version of Nuget.Server package got posted yesterday, probably after your post.  Perhaps this will fix the problem?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/nuget.server

Comment: Yes, it somehow fixed this problem

Thank you for bringing my attention to this new package version